# Convert multidimensional array to dictionary list

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a multidimensional dictionary that looks like

```
{
    "2023-10-02": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "2023-10-03": [
        7,
        8,
        9
    ]
}
```

and need to convert it to dictionary list

```
[
    {"2023-10-02": 1, "2023-10-03": 7},
    {"2023-10-02": 2, "2023-10-03": 8},
    {"2023-10-02": 3, "2023-10-03": 9}
]
```

any ideas to do that?

Comment: Stackoverflow is full of this kind of questions :)

Answer (score 0):

How about you take a look at this python code?

```
data = {
    "2023-10-02": [1, 2, 3],
    "2023-10-03": [7, 8, 9]
}

result = []

length = len(data["2023-10-02"])

for i in range(length):
    temp = {}
    for date, values in data.items():
        temp[date] = values[i]
    result.append(temp)

print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if get correctly your question, anyway, I show you some lines to get from your input your output:

```
input_data = {
    "2023-10-02": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "2023-10-03": [
        7,
        8,
        9
    ]
}
def get_your_dict_list(inp_data):
    output_list = []
    # Iterate through the values in the lists
    for values in zip(*input_data.values()):
        # Create a dictionary with keys from input dates and values from the current values in the lists
        output_dict = dict(zip(input_data.keys(), values))
        output_list.append(output_dict)
    
    return output_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
data = {
    "2023-10-02": [1, 2, 3],
    "2023-10-03": [7, 8, 9]
}

result = []

maxLength = 0 // each data partition may have variable length but result should have equal

for k in data.keys():
    maxLength = max(maxLength, data[k])

for i in range(maxLength)       
    temp = {}
        
    for date, values in codes.items():
        try:
            temp[date] = values[i]
        except Exception:
            temp[date] = None
            
        result.append(temp)

print(result)
```

Thanks to [Pascal Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22560097/pascal-dai) for idea